# Draw Median Value in Processing

Tags: processing, draw, visualization, median

I am working on a Data Viz project for Marriage Satisfaction & Breakup % in Processing.  I am struggling with where to pass values calculated by a `calculateMSatMedian` function and a `calculateBreakUpMedian` function.  The functions are returning correctly, but I don't know how to incorporate the `medianMSatis` and the `medianMBreakUp` into the `draw` function that lives in the `Source Class`.

Here's the code:

```
// GLOBAL DATA
Source sources[];            // our database of Source Types
int    nSources=0;       // number of Source Type Listings
float medianMBreakUp = 0.0;
float medianMSatis = 0.0;

// GLOBAL STATE
int currentplot=0;          // current view mode
Source offlineSource[] = new Source[0];
Source onlineDatingSource[] = new Source[0];
Source onlineSource[] = new Source[0];

// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
//                                                      setup
//                      ( PROCESSING:: default init function )
// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
void setup() {
  size(720,720, P3D);

  // load all data, with each record (i.e. text line) as a string
  String lines[]= loadStrings("MarriageSuccess-Table-S12.csv");

  nSources=lines.length-2; 

  sources=new Source[nSources];

  // create "Source" objects into database, with the line split by tabs
  //   ( "\t" == tab , "," == comma  , "\n" == carriage return/newline )
  for (int i=0; i<nSources; i++) {
    sources[i]=new Source(lines[i+1].split(","));
  }

  // create 'Source' arrays organized by source type
  //
  for (Source i : sources){
    if (i.type==1) {offlineSource = (Source[])append(offlineSource, i);}
    if (i.type==2) {onlineDatingSource = (Source[])append(onlineDatingSource, i);}
    if (i.type==3) {onlineSource = (Source[])append(onlineSource, i);}

    // calculate media values for Break Up % & Marital Satisfaction for each Type
    //
    for (Source j : offlineSource){
      calculateBreakUpMedian(offlineSource);
      calculateMSatMedian(offlineSource);
    }

    for (Source j : onlineDatingSource){
      calculateBreakUpMedian(onlineDatingSource);
      calculateMSatMedian(onlineDatingSource);
    } 
    for (Source j : onlineSource){
      calculateBreakUpMedian(onlineSource);
      calculateMSatMedian(onlineSource);
    } 
  }
}

// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
//                                                      draw
//                     ( PROCESSING:: default draw function )
// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
void draw() {
  background(180);
  drawInfo();
  for (int i=0; i<nSources; i++){
    sources[i].draw(currentplot);  
      println(sources[i].mSatisfaction);
      println("median " + medianMSatis); 
      // if (medianMSatis == sources[i].mSatisfaction) {
        // println("true");
        // fill the circle that contains the median value in the Offline, Online & Online         
        // Dating in counterplot 1(marital satisfaction) & counterplot 3(m breakup %)
      // }
  } 
}

// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
//                                      calculateBreakUpMedian
// calculate Break UP % Median Value For Individual Source Types
// accepts a type cast Source array
// ouptputs a float value
// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
void calculateBreakUpMedian(Source array[]) {
  if (array.length == 0) {
    println("nothing in the array.");
  } else {
    float[] breakUp = new float[0];
      for (Source i : array) {
        breakUp = append(breakUp, i.mBreakUp);
      }
    float max = max(breakUp);
    float min = min(breakUp);
    float range = max - min;
    medianMBreakUp = min + (range/2);
  }
}

// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
//                                                            calculateMSat Median
// calculate Marital Satisfaction Rating Median Value For Individual Source Types
// accepts a type cast Source array
// ouptputs a float value
// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
void calculateMSatMedian(Source array[]) {
  if (array.length == 0) {
    println("nothing in the array.");
  } else {
    float[] mSat = new float[0];
    for (Source i : array) {
      mSat = append(mSat, i.mSatisfaction);
    }
  float max = max(mSat);
  float min = min(mSat);
  float range = max - min;
  medianMSatis = min + (range/2);
  }
}
```

Comment: Try this: copy-paste your code into the Processing IDE. Notice that hitting "run" throws up compile errors. `void setup()` and `void draw()` are fixed functions in the Processing programming model. Don't try to overload them, make new functions if you need to house bits of code in their own functions. Also, `draw(int x, y, z)` is not legal Processing in the slightest, you need types for all those parameters. Finally: can you reduce this code to only the bits that go wrong? A lot of this code is entirely unrelated to your problem, please prune it.

Comment: Thanks MIke - been working in the processing IDE all night.  BTW just discovered your tuts on Processing.js today - thx.  For some reason it's running fine and not throwing any errors, if you look in the draw function though when I set `medianMSatis == sources[i].mSatisfaction` it won't go into the `if` statement to highlight the circle that contains the `medianMSatis` values in each `offlineSource onlineSource` and `onlineDatingSource`.

Comment: okay, but now you removed the entire Source class so we still can't run this code =( On a functional note, you really want to use ArrayLists<Source>, not primitive arrays. They're much nicer to work with.